# MySQL: Retrieve data from Parent Table if it's Child Table's sum of QtyIn is greater than the sum of QtyOut

Tags: mysql, data-retrieval

Here's my scenario:

```
Table A     Table B 
IDa = 1     IDb = 1 | IDa = 1 | QtyIn = 2 | QtyOut = 0
IDa = 2     IDb = 2 | IDa = 1 | QTyIn = 0 | QtyOut = 1 
            IDb = 3 | IDa = 2 | QtyIn = 1 | QtyOut = 0
            IDb = 4 | IDa = 2 | QtyIn = 0 | QtyOut = 1
```

I want to retrieve rows from Table A if the sum of its Table B's QtyIn is greater than the sum of its QtyOut. Table B will be grouped by the column IDa. In this example, IDa = 1 of Table A is the only row that will be retrieved because of it's remaining stock. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for both tables, example data for them (3-5 rows each) as INSERT INTO, and desired result as textual formatted table. Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: I second Akina's comment and add query/queries that you've tried so far, [Put all those in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65031839/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to select the columns you need so in this case

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
```

Next you need to decide what tables you need so in this case you also need table B:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM TABLEA, TABLEB
```

Next you should figure out your join condition in this case:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM TABLEA, TABLEB
WHERE TABLEA.IDa = TABLEB.IDa
```

Finally you want to go to the Aggregate Function and do the calculations you sql should look like the following:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM TABLEA, TABLEB
WHERE TABLEA.IDa = TABLEB.IDa
Group by TABLEB.IDa
Having SUM(QtyIn - QtyOut) > 0
```

So yep that should be all...

Comment: This was almost the correct answer. I had to change the Group by TABLEA.IDa to TABLEB.IDa before it worked. I'm going to mark this as the answer if you edit it

Comment: @Sirc.Sbat Edited it,  but just so you know the requirements that you gave us were not exactly clear on what you wanted to group by, just so you know.... :)

Comment: Please note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992.

Comment: @YunfeiChen Yeah, I'm sorry it wasn't really clear. That's why I still marked your answer correct even though I asked you to edit it